# Getting ANR dialog while starting a service in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, android-anr-dialog

I'm  using a service to to play radio, when the app is running in the background. My app contains 4 radio channels. So I have used a viewpager. When i swipe slowly, my app responds properly. But when I swipe quickly, my app is not responding & I'm getting a ANR dialog. As per the documentaion, a service runs as a separate thread. So it should not block my app. But to be on safer side, I added service inside async task. But still the same problem. I tested it on Nexus 5 device. But When I run the app on emulator(Nexus 5-Lollipop). It works perfectly. Then what might be the problem? Is anyone facing a similar problem.
This is how I start my service:

```
     private void playRadio() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
                        if (PreferencesManager.getInstance(getActivity()).isLiveRadioPlaying())
                            stopRadio();
                        Log.d("Visible", "");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LiveRadioService.class);
                        intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
                        intent.putExtra(RADIO_URL, mRadioUrl);
                        intent.putExtra(RADIO_TITLE, mSectionTitle);
                        intent.putExtra(LIVE_RADIO_SECTION_POSITION, mSectionPos);
                        getActivity().startService(intent);

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }

Preparing the media player inside asynctask:
   private void playRadio() {
 new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
 try {

            cancelNotification();

            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mUrl);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: I solved my problem. When media player was in preparing state, If i try to reset the media player, media player doesn't respond. Hence, getting ANR. So I'm waiting for media player to prepare completely and then reset the media player if url is different. this solved my issue and not getting aNR anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> As per the documentaion, a service runs as a separate thread.

*Not True*

Because [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) always run in same process of Application but *worker thread* is used by  [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to process received the Intents.

> I'm getting a ANR dialog

Probably Service doing some network related work or Api calls on Main Thread.

To prevent ANR dialog launch separate Thread or use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), `IntentService`  to do intensive or blocking operations in Service

Comment: I tried using async task..But still the same problem. In the service, my using a mediaplayer..Is it beacuse of the media player? And y it is working perfectly in emulator

Comment: @AmandaFernandez: MediaPlayer with web url probably causing issue so use MediaPlayer.setDataSource,MediaPlayer.prepare(); methods inside AsyncTask

Comment: I started service using async task..So media player will also come inside the  thread rite..Then y separate thread for mediaplayer..But ill try putting the thread

Comment: @AmandaFernandez: `I started service using async task`  no this is not right way. you should use `AsyncTask` inside service for preparing or playing mediaplayer

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K, I tried as you suggested. I used asynctask while preparing the media player.Still the same results. Infact I'm not getting ANR on devices below kitkat.. Is there something specific to lollypop has to be done?